# How can I calculate the limit without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, theorem-proving

I need to prove this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+a\,x)^{1/4} - (1+b\,x)^{1/4}}{x} = \frac{a-b}{4}$$

How can I do it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I have decided not to close this question or migrate, because it has a sensible Mathematica-based answer. As such it will still be useful to the community, even if the OP wasn't actually wanting a Mathematica solution. There is only one more vote needed to close, and I'm happy to be overruled.

Answer (score 16):

One can simply use:

```
Limit[((1 + a x)^(1/4) - (1 + b x)^(1/4))/x, x -> 0]
```

to get the result. However `Limit` does know about the l'Hopital rule.
Nonetheless there are different ways to go, e.g. let's use `Series` to write down the first few terms of the Taylor series of  `((1 + a x)^(1/4) - (1 + b x)^(1/4))/x`:

```
Series[((1 + a x)^(1/4) - (1 + b x)^(1/4))/x, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> ```
>  (a - b)/4 - 3/32 (a^2 - b^2) x + 7/128 (a^3 - b^3) x^2 
>   - (77 (a^4 - b^4) x^3)/2048 + O[x]^4
> ```

This demonstrates clearly what the limit of the expression is when `x -> 0`. Unfortunately this still uses some analytical methods and it might be especially useful if we can get rid of them.

### Elementary Proof

Therefore we can provide quite an **elementary proof** (only ancient Greeks' methods). 
We take the expression `((1 + a x)^(1/4) - (1 + b x)^(1/4))` and multiply it by

```
expr1 = ((1 + a x)^(1/4) + (1 + b x)^(1/4));
```

The latter term is equal to `2` at `x == 0` (`expr1 /. x -> 0` yields `2`).

```
((1 + a x)^(1/4) - (1 + b x)^(1/4)) ((1 + a x)^(1/4) + (1 + b x)^(1/4)) // Expand
```

> ```
> Sqrt[1 + a x] - Sqrt[1 + b x]
> ```

Now we take `Sqrt[1 + a x] - Sqrt[1 + b x]` and we multiply it by

```
expr2 = Sqrt[1 + a x] + Sqrt[1 + b x];
```

similarily the latter term is equal to `2` at `x == 0`. Now we have:

```
(Sqrt[1 + a x] - Sqrt[1 + b x]) (Sqrt[1 + a x] + Sqrt[1 + b x]) // Expand
```

> ```
> a x - b x
> ```

We have multiplied the interesting term twice by `2` and now we take the denominator (i.e. `x`) of the initial exppession. Thus we can see from the last output that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{(1 + a x)^{\frac{1}{4}} - (1 + b x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{x}=\frac{a-b}{4}$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: I am guessing this is math homework and should be migrated, don't you think so?

Comment: Not necessarily, I demonstrated what the OP wanted without the l'Hopital rule. I could also provide another ways. Just showed something for those about to study calculus, with the help of _Mathematica_. Right?

Comment: Ok, we will see what the OP says anyways.

Comment: i'm sure its trivial to show that the series converges, but i'd think you need to show that step to offer this up as proof.

Comment: @george2079 Now you have got what you wanted.

Comment: Nice, I like this way much better :)

Answer (score 12):

First, let us notice that the limit follows from the following:

**Lemma.** $\displaystyle \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} {(1+u)^{1/4}-1 \over u} = {1 \over 4}$.

For

$${{(1+a\,x)^{1/4} - (1+b\,x)^{1/4}} \over {x}} =
 {{(1+a\,x)^{1/4} - 1} \over {x}} - {{(1+b\,x)^{1/4} - 1} \over {x}}$$
$$ = a\,{{(1+u)^{1/4} - 1} \over {u}} - b\,{{(1+v)^{1/4} - 1} \over {v}}\,,$$

where $u = ax$ and $v = bx$.

### *Mathematica* proofs

*Sans L'Hôpital:*

The nub of a proof is an equality like this:

```
Simplify[Abs[((1 + u)^(1/4) - 1)/u - 1/4] < Abs[u], -1 < u < 1 && u != 0]
(* True *)
```

More directly from the definition:

```
Resolve[ForAll[epsilon, 
  Implies[epsilon > 0, 
   Exists[delta, 
    ForAll[u, 
     Implies[Abs[u] < delta && u != 0, 
      Abs[((1 + u)^(1/4) - 1)/u - 1/4] < epsilon]]]]],
 Reals
 ]
(* True *)
```

### Another elementary proof

*Proof á la Euclid.* [Prompted by @Artes's remark about ancient Greeks.]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let $BX$ be given with $OA=OB=1$ and $AX = u>0$.  Let $OP$ have been drawn perpendicular to $BX$ with $OC=1$.  Let  $BX$ have been bisected at $Q$.  With center $Q$ and distance $QX$, let circle $XPB$ have been described.  Let $PQ$ be joined. Then $PQ = BQ = 1+u/2$ and $OP = \sqrt{1+u}$; further $OP < PQ = BQ$.  Subtracting $BO = OC = 1$ yields $ CP = \sqrt{1+u}-1 < OQ = u/2$.

On the other hand, let $QM$, $XH$ have been drawn perpendicular to $OX$, and let $CG$ and $PH$ have been drawn perpendicular to $OP$.  Let $PX$ have been joined and intersect $QM$ at $K$.  Finally let a line have been drawn perpendicular to $QM$ at $K$.  The complements $OK$, $KH$ of the diagonal $PX$ are equal [Eucl. I.43].  Therefore the rectangle $CH$ is greater than the rectangle $OK$ which is greater than $OG$.  Thus $CH = (1+u)(\sqrt{1+u}-1) > u/2$.

Therefore
$${u \over 2(1+u)} < \sqrt{1+u}-1 < {u \over 2}$$
or
$$1 + {u \over 2(1+u)} < \sqrt{1+u} < 1 + {u \over 2}$$

Similarly, letting $OX = \sqrt{1+u}$, we obtain
$$1 + { \sqrt{1+u}-1 \over 2( \sqrt{1+u})} < (1+u)^{1/4} < 1 + {\sqrt{1+u}-1 \over 2}$$
Applying the previous inequalities, we have
$$1 + {u \over 4(1+u/2)} < 1 + { \sqrt{1+u}-1 \over 2( \sqrt{1+u})} \quad\hbox{and}\quad
 1 + {\sqrt{1+u}-1 \over 2} < 1 + {u \over 4}\,.$$
 From this we get
 $$1 + {u \over 4(1+u/2)} < (1+u)^{1/4} < 1 + {u \over 4}\,.$$
It follows that
$$\left| {(1+u)^{1/4} -1 \over u} - {1 \over 4} \right| < {u \over 8 + 4u} < u\,.$$

Similarly, taking $X$ between $O$ and $A$ so that $AX = -u$, one can show that
$$\left| {(1+u)^{1/4} -1 \over u} - {1 \over 4} \right| < {-u}\,,$$
provided $-1/2 < u < 0$.
Thus the lemma is established.

### Calculus proof

The limit in the lemma is the derivative of $x^{1/4}$ at $x = 1$.

---

### Code dump for figure

```
labels[u_] := MapThread[Text, Transpose[{
     {"O", {0, 0}, {0, 1.5}},
     {"A", {1, 0}, {0, 1.5}},
     {"B", {-1, 0}, {-1.8, 1.5}},
     {"C", {0, 1}, {1.5, 0}},
     {"X", {1 + u, 0}, {-1.8, 1.5}},
     {"P", {0, Sqrt[1 + u]}, {1.5, -1}},
     {"Q", {u/2, 0}, {0, 1.5}},
     {"G", {u/2, 1}, {1.5, 1.5}},
     {"H", {1 + u, Sqrt[1 + u]}, {-1.8, -1}},
     {"K", {u/2, (2 + u)/2/Sqrt[1 + u]}, {-2, -1.5}},
     {"L", {u/2, 1}, {-2.7, 1.5}},
     {"M", {u/2, Sqrt[1 + u]}, {0., -2.5}}
     }]];
Manipulate[
 With[{u = Exp[logu]},
  Graphics[
   {Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0},
      {1 + u, 0}, {u/2, 0}, {0, Sqrt[1 + u]}}],
    Circle[{u/2, 0}, 1 + u/2],
    Line[{{{-1, 0}, {1 + u, 0}, {1 + u, Sqrt[1 + u]}, {0, Sqrt[
        1 + u]}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1 + u, 1}}, {{u/2, 0}, {u/2, Sqrt[
        1 + u]}}, {{u/2, 0}, {0, Sqrt[1 + u]}, {1 + u, 
        0}}, {{0, (2 + u)/2/Sqrt[1 + u]}, {1 + u, (2 + u)/2/Sqrt[
         1 + u]}}}],
    labels[u]
    },
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 2.1}, {-0.5, 1.5}},
   ImageSize -> 400
   ]
  ],
 {{logu, -0.3}, -3., 0.}
 ]
```

Comment: To suggest correctness of the stated Lemma, in *Mathematica* one might look at `Series[((1 + u)^(1/4) - 1)/u, {u, 0, 10}]`, say. (Mathematically, one still must worry about whether the series in fact converges in some interval about 0.)

Comment: @murray Yes, Artes's answer points out the use of `Limit` and `Series`.  I didn't think the lemma different enough to warrant pointing it out here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I like it i.e. geometric reasoning.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for the gorgeous manipulable geometric figure!

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
\frac{(1+a\,x)^{1/4} - (1+b\,x)^{1/4}}{x}=(a-b)\frac{(1+a\,x)^{1/4} - (1+b\,x)^{1/4}}{(1+a\ x)-(1+b\ x)}
$$

and now

$$
\frac{u^4-v^4}{u-v} = (u^2+v^2)(u+v)
$$

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this problem can also be analyzed with infinitesimal symbols:

```
((1 + a x + c*x^2 + O[x]^3)^(1/4) - (1 + b x + O[x]^3)^(1/4))
```

We can clearly see that even adding some infinitesimal terms of order will not affect the results.