# How can I calculate the limit without using the L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Solve

$$\lim x \to2  \frac{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{4x-8}}}{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x+2}}}} $$

Comment: Where is your try in *Mathematica*?

Comment: You could expand in Taylor seres numerator and denominator sepately. Then take the limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the limit without using the L'Hopital's rule](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46114/how-can-i-calculate-the-limit-without-using-the-lhopitals-rule)

Comment: From seeing some of this users' posts, I do get the strong impression that his user name is a rather verbose indication of "zero effort". Thus I downvoted this and also voted to close this as it belongs to a different site as it is.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a finite series expansion about the point `x==2` and then evaluate with "x==2": `Series[f, {x, 2, 2}] /. x -> 2`

Answer (score 3):

Another way: use Taylor series as I said in my comment.

```
n = Series[1 - Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[4 x - 8]], {x, 2, 1}];
d = Series[1 - Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[(x - 2)/(x + 2)]], {x, 2, 1}];

Limit[n/d, x -> 2]

(*4*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother any technique, when `Limit` can give you the answer!

```
f = (1 - Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[4*x - 8]])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[(x - 2)/(x + 2)]])
Limit[f, x -> 2]
```

> 4