# Unexpected Indeterminate result from evaluating a limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, syntax, number-representation

Consider

$\qquad \underset{h\to 0}{\text{lim}}\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{h+x}-\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt{h+x}-\sqrt{x}}$

Here is what I get when I evaluate it Mathematica:

[image: MMA output]

When I calculate it by hand and in other applications, it results in

$\qquad \dfrac{1}{ 2 \sqrt[4]{x}}$

Syntax error in Mathematica?

#### Update

It is not that I do not know how to calculate the limit, I have easily done it by hand without derivatives and with the rule of L'hopital. I find it strange, that when writing it using one of the assistant palettes, it evaluated to `Indeterminate`. I imagined that I had to put an extra condition.

That's why I thought maybe I needed a condition for `x` , let's say `x > 0`, but I didn't know how to write it.

This result threw me. Now, I did it again and it I got the correct result (maybe some variable in memory was bothering me).

Comment: This limit is immediatelly calculated by hand. You should not  use *Mathematica* to figure it out.  Nethertheless take a look at [How can I calculate the limit without using L'Hôpital's rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46114/how-can-i-calculate-the-limit-without-using-lh%c3%b4pitals-rule/46115#46115)

Comment: @Artes_see update above

Comment: Possibly you had set `x` to 0?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one can reproduce the problem the OP is experiencing; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Comment: This Question has no question.

Comment: @BeTDa It's still unclear what you tried. Please provide Mathematica code of your input "In[27]" .Thanks!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann  That's all the code, I wrote it using the MMA's teaching assistant, surely it was set in memory at some point x=0, as I was told.
At that time and several times later I always got a long time, I thought about putting a restriction, but I did not know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to the only question-like feature of the edited Question,

```
Assuming[{x > 0},
    Limit[ /* more stuff here */ ]
]
```

Comment: ,That was missing, I thought that the limit was not working for me because the "x" was not defined.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica

```
Limit[((h + x)^(1/4) - ( x)^(1/4))/((h + x)^(1/2) - ( x)^(1/2)),h -> 0]
(*1/(2 x^(1/4))*)
```

evaluates the limit without problems

Comment: see update above

Comment: @BeTDa It's still unclear what you tried. Please provide Mathematica code of your input "In[27]" .Thanks!

Comment: Ulrich Neumann That's all the code, I wrote it using the MMA's teaching assistant, surely it was set in memory at some point x=0, as I was told. At that time and several times later I always got a long time, I thought about putting a restriction, but I did not know how to do it

Comment: @BeTDa A pixel image can't be "all the code" , that's my question